# Почему Spring не видит файл конфигурации?

Tags: java, spring, config

Создал файл конфигурации в папке *meta*, но Spring упорно отказывается его замечать. Хотя *File* пишет что файл существует.

```
public class DemoApplication{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    File file = new File("meta/context-food.xml");
    System.out.println(file.exists());
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("meta/context-food.xml");
    ctx.refresh();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Spring кидает IOException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ошибку. Нужно было добавить в load()

```
.load(new PathResource("путь"));
```